# Notepad++: select text till the end of visual line with SHIFT+END

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, text-editors

In Notepad++, when I press SHIFT+END to select text from the current caret position till the end of the current visual line, the whole logical line till its end limited with CR/LF is selected.

An example. If the caret is in the very first position in a text document, I get this after pressing SHIFT+END:

[image: Notepad++: SHIFT+END selects till the end of logical line]

However what I need is this:

[image: Notepad++: SHIFT+END should select till the end of visual line]

It seems this is the standard behavior in all well-known document editors including the built-in Windows Notepad & Microsoft Word. How to achieve this in Notepad++? Is there a setting, or another keyboard command for this?

Comment: I'd be curious about what happens if you press End (instead of Shift End), what happens when you press Ctrl-End, and what happens when you use SC1 or SCiTE (both available from the SCiTE site), since Notepad++ is based on SCiTE.  [link]http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html

Comment: @TOOGAM, End works as expected - moves the caret to the end of the visual line. IMHO, now all this is not important as we have a working solution suggested by boot13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can produce the desired behaviour using the Notepad++ Shortcut Mapper. From the menu, select **Settings** > **Shortcut Mapper...**, click the **Scintilla commands** button, and scroll down to **SCI_LINEENDWRAPEXTEND**.

In my install of Notepad++, this command has no keyboard shortcut by default. Double-click the entry and select **Shift** and **End** on the Shortcut dialog. Click the **Add** button, then the **OK** button.

Now you need to get rid of the old shortcut: find the entry for **SCI_LINEENDEXTEND** and edit it. Change the shortcut to something you're unlikely to use, like **Ctrl-Alt-Shift-End**, then click **OK**.

Pressing **Shift-End** should now select the current line to the right side of the screen as desired. Pressing it again should extend the selection to the next line.

Comment: Excellent!! I just set SCI_LINEENDEXTEND to 'None' in my configuration as I do not see any need in this feature.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that was an option. Cool! I'm thinking about making that my default setup for Notepad++. I noticed this behaviour before but didn't look into a workaround until I saw your question.

Comment: I also set the mirror command to move the caret to the first character of the current line by the **Home** key. This is **SCI_HOMEDISPLAY**. For selection, the corresponding command is **SCI_HOMEDISPLAYEXTEND**.